# Why are particles showing up outside my weight painted areas?

Tags: particles, weight-painting

I'm following Andrew Price's new donut tutorial level 2 part 1 (link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNmnPXY9UQA).

Please see attached screenshot. I only have one vertex group and one particle effect in my scene.

[image: Donut icing weight paint]

Comment: Have you tried manually setting the areas that should have no sprinkles to a weight of 0 in edit mode? I find that weight painting can sometimes give very small weights that are hard to see in certain areas.

Comment: @Brenticus Blender newbie here -- do you mean manually painting weight 0 over those dark blue edges?

Comment: Not quite. In edit mode on the icing, select the areas where you want no sprinkles, then under the vertex group options (the place where you made the group) choose remove.